# AngularJS calculate a dynamic number of variables in braces

Tags: angularjs

I want to calculate the total sum, of a dynamic number of variables within angular's brace syntax.

The for loop I would normally use would look like :

```
var total = 0;
for(x=0; x< objects.length; x++) {
    total += objects[x].num;
}
```

I would like to recreate this as `{{ total }}` or `{{total()}}` and have the total update when ever one of the variables is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6hm4L7c/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-strict-di>
    {{total()}}<br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.num" ng-repeat="item in objects"/>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('ctrl',function($scope) {

    angular.extend($scope,{
        objects:[
            {num:7},
            {num:8},
            {num:9}

            ],
        total : function(){
            var res = 0;
            for (var i=0;i<$scope.objects.length;i++) 
                res+=parseInt($scope.objects[i].num);
            return res;
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**
To test if it's updating the total on object's num update play with code like this:

```
 setInterval(function() {
    $scope.objects[1].num++;
    $scope.$apply();
 },500); //increase num of 2nd object by 1, every half of second
```

To test if it's still updating when adding new objects, play with code like that:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $scope.objects.push({num:Math.floor(Math.random()*100)});
},5000); //Add new object, with random num: value, every 5 seconds
```

Comment: Nice! Is `.extend` needed here?

Comment: No, it's just nice way of doing $scope.objects= ... and $scope.total = ... that I usually use

Comment: Will this auto update when one of the variables is changed?  Or will I have to  re-fire the calculation.

Comment: Yes, it will auto update, if you ever bind these variables, like in the example I've used (ng-model)
It depends on the way you change them.

Comment: I've updated example, with an example of how you can update values: http://jsfiddle.net/r6hm4L7c/1/

Comment: but surely the function won't recalculate unless re-fired?

Comment: but it seems to be doing just that in the fiddle?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question.
Here is pure/clean example: http://jsfiddle.net/r6hm4L7c/2/
"total" is not being re-fired until one of the properties (or subproperties) of $scope are changed.
In your case, you change property of elements inside array that is inside $scope. That is why everytime you change it, total gets refired. not vice versa

Comment: is there another way we could bind it to re-fire every time a new object is added?

Comment: Yes, there is. Angular does it automatically, just push new object to the array.
I've updated the answer, and JSFiddle, demo-eing that